# Strange div floating behaviour

Tags: css-float, html

Please explain why does the div with "asd" content goes below red div?

http://jsfiddle.net/krEqQ/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="class0">0</div>
<div style="padding-left: 150px;">
<div class="class1">1<br>1</div>
<div class="class1">2<br>2</div>
<div class="class1">3</div>    
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div>asd</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.class0 {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
}

.class1 {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 50px 50px 0;
}
```

I assume it should comes right after 3rd div with class class1(on the right space where in this example is empty). Isn't clear both should clear floating stuff within parent container but not in entire document?

Comment: because of the `clear: both` styled div

Comment: can you specify where you want that div?

Comment: Because of that, but I think he asked why there is space from elft. It is because you ahve not closed div which ahs padding-left:150 px

Comment: I assume it should comes right after 3rd div with class class1. Isn't clear both should clear floating stuff within parent but not in entire document?

Comment: Yeah here was a typo, but I closed this div and stil it goes at the same place

Answer (score 0):

`clear:both` makes it slide down.
Where do you want it?